# Novel in which the protagonist cultivates to become so powerful that he destroys his world and then reincarnates into another world

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai, reincarnation, cultivation

This is either a Korean, Japanese or Chinese novel.

In it, the male protagonist cultivates to become so powerful that he destroys/kills his whole world subsequently drawing the wrath of a heavenly tribulation which in turn kills him. He then reincarnates into another world into a pretty rich family. Since he actually older than what he seems, his family is creeped out by him and his coldness. He eventually kills his family then joins a sect. He enters the sect as an outer discipline killing his way into the inner sect. He then proceeds to kill and slaughter everybody in and out his sect. He is eventually discovered and misunderstood to be an elder of the sect who took control of a younger person body. When in reality he actually an all powerful cultivator from another world who destroyed his own world.

I forgot the name and title, but any help finding it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and did you read it online? If you did, you recall which site you might have read it on?

Comment: I read it online and I believe I read it in 2022. Unfortunately I do not remember the website.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'a sect of correct'?

Comment: Sorry typo, he enter a sect but I can’t remember the sect name or type but pretty sure it was an evil sect.